# What is the highly efficient way to remove a block of string pattern in php file? Given scenario

Tags: php, security, preg-replace, server

Scenario:

Supposing there are many many files under a server directory.

Assuming all correct *.php files are as simple and clean as below

```
<?php //slience is gold ?>
```

then someday suddenly all the php files got infected, like below.

```
<?php infected codes multiple block lines ?><?php //slience is gold ?>
```

Normal solution those answers

i got from other ppl to do such block string replacements are all using IDE tools.

```
Step1: making sure you downloaded the files and open file directory with IDE.
Step2: shift+R(shortkey for replacement command), 
key in the "string pattern" replaced with "" blank string marker, 
and replace them recursively in directory.
```

However, considering there are millions of php files infected with the above patterns suddenly and you've to make a quick response to clean the unwanted code patterns. If we still using the IDE pattern replacement method , sure it confirm can work but will take a long long time in file transferring via below tedious procedures.

```
 1.downloading directory where contains infected php files.
 2. open directory with IDE in local computer disk
 3. recursively string pattern replacement 
 4. re-upload all files again to remoute directory.
```

So finally my question here is trying to figure out are there highly efficient ways or refine the procedures to achieve this task with less human involvements/interactions like the four steps taken in the above IDE method.

Comment: Don't you have a backup?

Comment: thanks for the comment @M42 , Backup is independent with this senario though it's the most useful way we can restore everything via override with clean files,but the process still take time considering when the files are really big.(backup at local can not avoid uploading time cost, backup at server cost space.) Besides, even when backup method is valid, most ppl are not rich enough to afford a real-time backup plan, if the file modification happens between the periodically backup intervals It's hard to say there might be more possibilities that u miss out some updates after your last backup.

Comment: Besides, it's relatively unfair in their effort contrast comparing the time cost spent on clean backup file to override all infected files (supposing u've taken 2hour to finally settle override in order not to miss any files) while the attacker might be able run a script to recursively inject everything again effortlessly without much human participation (code run by itself).  ---during the above assumption, we neglect the improper configuration flaws in apache, meaning if we set chmod of all files to higher access permmision those files won't be able to change, it's true.